# Switch statement not compiling

Tags: c, switch-statement

Hello I've been sitting here for quite some time trying to figure out why this isn't working but I haven't had luck succeeding!

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(void)
{
    int mark;

    printf("Please enter the mark\n");
    scanf("%d", &mark);

    switch(mark){
        case (mark <40):
            printf("That's a fail");
            break;
        case (mark >=40 && <60):
            printf("That's a pass");
            break;
        case (mark >=60 && <70):
            printf("That's a merit");
            break;
        case (mark >=70):
            printf("That's a distinction");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say doesn't work - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Welp, I've got to be honest :D

Comment: It's producing an error in the compiler

Comment: For future reference maybe include the compiler error too. You can also google the error and perhaps find the answer too.

Comment: use if/else buddy, instead switch

Answer (score 4):

For comparisons where the exact value is not known, use if-else blocks. You are trying to use a switch statement like an if-else block, and it does not work properly. A proper switch would look like

```
switch(mark) {
case 40: //if mark is 40, no more, no less
  ...
case 60: //same
 ...
}
```

Because you don't want to write out 40 lines that all lead to the same statement, just use

```
if(mark < 40) { ... }
else if(mark < 60) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

From K&R:

"The switch statement is a mult-way decision that tests whether an expression matches one of a number of *constant integer values*, and branches accordingly."

That is, you can't do what you're trying to do. Each case needs a constant statement, such a simple int or char value.

For what you want to do you'll need if/else. Also, see jaap's answer on correct syntax for your boolean statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine, the compiler is preventing you from compiling something that's not valid C.

The `case` labels must be actual integer constants, not expressions that do further calculations.

You should use `if`/`else if` to check your various conditions.